# nullobject for File in Java

Tags: java, design-patterns, file, null, mocking

I have a class that occasionally gets passed `null` for `File` objects. During normal operation it uses a `Scanner` class to parse through the file.

Instead of littering my code with `null` checks against the `File` objects, I thought I could replace the `File`s with nullobjects (Gang of Four style).

However, it looks like `File` isn't really designed to be extended. Does any one have any pointers on how to do this?

Comment: what do you mean it isn't designed to be extended?

Comment: What I meant was "design to be replaced with a completely different implementation with the same interface."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace the object that uses the file with a NullObject

For instance, you can use a NullInputStream and pass it to the scanner.

Before:

```
 public void whatever( File f ) { 

     Scanner scanner = new Scanner( f );

     ...
 }
```

After

```
 public void whatever( File f ) { 

      Scanner scanner = new Scanner( getInputStreamFrom( f ) );

      ...
 }
```

And have that method implemented like:

```
 private final InputStream getInputStreamFrom( File f ) {

      if( f == null && !f.exists() ) { 
          return NullInputStream.instance;
      }

      return new InputStream( new FileInputStream( f ) );

 }


 class NulllInputStream extends InputStream {

      private final static NullInputStream instance = new NullInputStream();

      private NullInputStream() {
      }

      public int read() { 
          return -1; 
      }
      .... other relevant methods here... 
 }
```

Obviously coded carefully and not in 3 mins. as I did :) :) :)

Comment: There's even an implementation of this in Apache Commons: http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/input/NullInputStream.html

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you just control the entry point of the `File` object into your program's logic and perform the `null` check there?

Another option would be to use something like a separate interface which encapsulates the data: a `Reader` for example. You could certainly provide a `NullReader` implementation

Answer (score 1):

The null object pattern was designed around interfaces, not concrete objects.

To get around this, you can create a new interface which contains the methods you are using from `File`, and then create a concrete implementation which just delegates to a `File` held inside.  Then, you can create your null implementation, which will stub out the calls.

Of course, this seems like a bit of overkill for removing one null check.