# Null Object Pattern for FileInfo

Tags: c#, .net, file, design-patterns, fileinfo

I have a method which returns a `FileInfo`-object. After calling the method `fooFile.FullName` is called.

All fine but there is a case where `FileInfo` can be `null`, but I don't want (ugly) null-checks where the method is called.

What I neet is some kind of null-FileInfo ([Null-Object-Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern)). It would be enough when calling `fooFile.FullName` returns a empty string.
Unfortunately `new FileInfo(string.Empty)` doesn't work.

Searching SO bring this [java-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128387/nullobject-for-file-in-java), but answers didn't help me.

Is there a way to use `FileInfo` in combination with Null-Object-Pattern?

Comment: If an object can be null, a null-check is not ugly. But you could also use the `Try`-pattern: `FileInfo fi; if(TryGetFile(path,out fi)){}`.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter: Thanks for your input Tim. My method is used on a lot of places. So I don't to implement (redundant) null-checks for every call. `TryGetFile` is interesting, but same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `??` operator to use a default `FileInfo` where needed, with a static variable somewhere representing what is the default fileinfo:

```
public void MyMethod(FileInfo fi)
{
    // use default fileinfo if null is passed to this method
    fi = fi ?? DefaultFileInfo.Value;

    // method code...
    // do something with the fileinfo, it is not null for sure now.
}
```

The default file info class:

```
public static class DefaultFileInfo
{
    public static readonly FileInfo Value = new FileInfo("null");
}
```

If you what to make the default file readable, of course you would need to specify a valid file name.

Comment: Thanks! That put me in the right way. I try `new FileInfo(string.Empty);` but your `new FileInfo("null");` works as I need. +1 for that.

Answer (score 3):

What is exactly the problem with the null check? I don't see your point...
If you *really* want to avoid this null check, you can use an extension method, but I cannot recommand you to do that...

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string GetFullName(this FileInfo fInfo)
    {
        if (fInfo == null)
        {
            return String.Empty;
        }
        return fInfo.FullName;
    }
}
```

And then

```
FileInfo fInfo = // ... ;
string fullName = fInfo.GetFullName();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer (+1 for that). I don't want this null-checks, because every time I (or someone else) use the method I have to think that null-check is necessary. If I (or someone else) forget it, it may leads me to runtime exceptions.

Comment: You don't have to check everytime! The check is done in the extension method.

Comment: `FileInfo fInfo = null; string fullName = fInfo.GetFullName()` <-- no null check, no exception